# Cannot return null for non-nullable field PostgresDatabaseSchema.search_path

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I'm currently working with Heroku dataclips and I'm coming across this error where it says that it is unable to fetch schema, cannot return null for non-nullable field PostgresDatabaseSchema.search_path. I'm not exactly sure what might be the cause of this, since the search_path seems to be showing up correctly in console and the dataclips seem to be correctly querying the tables.